# CListView with ajax

Tags: yii

I am new to Yii, I am trying to get a CListView to update using ajax instead of refreshing the page. To make the simplest example, I am just feeding the CListView with a dataprovider and giving it the itemView parameter, nothing else. I want the pagination to update the page without refreshing. It works with gii generated crud pages but will not work with mine. I have added nothing extra, the code for the gii generated example and my own should be the same. Is there some setup step I am missing? Is there javascript missing in my layout that the default layout has perhaps? Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you post your view and controller code ?

Comment: Is there javascript missing in my layout that the default layout has perhaps?  - we don't know because we can't see your code....

Comment: Its supposed to work with ajax only..check console for js errors..

Comment: Thanks Rajat. I was working on it from last 2 hours and solution was too simple

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I was loading jQuery in my layout which was interfering with the jQuery library automatically loaded in Yii. Simply removing my jQuery include solved the problem. I will chalk this one up to being new at Yii and not knowing the inner workings of how it automatically includes javascript. Thanks guys, Rajat you put my mind on the right track, thanks.